# How to stop worker thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I found and use some method bellow but it is not work for me:

```
myThread.stop() //it is not safe but I am tried that
myThread.interupt
```

- Here is my program: I wanna play video using Videoview when video finish. If user no choose the next video in 120s then my app will finish.
  My video view code:

  ```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(filePath);
    videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    waitingThread w8 = new waitingThread();


    //set params video before play
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(mediaPlayer -> {
        PlaybackParams playbackParams = new PlaybackParams();
        playbackParams.setSpeed(DeviceConfig.getInstance().getVideoPeed());// 1.25 1.5 2 2.5
        mediaPlayer.setPlaybackParams(playbackParams);
        // I am tryied using stop thread here
        // w8.stop()
        // or w8.interrupt();
        videoView.start();

    });


    videoView.setOnErrorListener((mediaPlayer, i, i1) -> {
        Log.d(TAG,"Video Error");
        //send error message to server

        return false;
    });

    //I call thread when video complete
    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            **waiting();** -> w8.start //edited i start thread here
        }
    });
  ```

My thread waiting

```
private  class waitingThread extends Thread{

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!isInterrupted()) {

                timeCount ++;
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Log.d(TAG, "Time count : " + timeCount);
                if(timeCount == 120){
                   finish();
                 }

            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //i am try to using this funtion but still not work too.
    public void stopping(){
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
//            timeCount = 0;
    //            Log.d(TAG, "Stopping, reset time :" + timeCount);
            }

    }
```

Brief my idea: When video start play, thread waiting will be stopped. When video finish program will waiting a time if no video chose in time to wait program will finish, if any video chose then thread w8 stop.

My problem: when I choose the next video, my thread "w8" still keep running. That is make my app finished while video playing
Plz help me how to fix that problem or any same idea to work are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to call interrupt on Thread.currentThread.  Thread.currentThread is the thread currently running-  it's the thread you're calling the function on.  It's not the thread object you just created.  Instead it would be this.interrupt().  Or just get rid of the function entirely and call interrupt directly.

Comment: you are right. I am show the ID of the thread, it  show difference between thread created and thread called interrupt. But "this.interrupt()" not work.  If I play more video then more thread will created. More info about my app: I play video in second Activity, and that activity destroy each time new video chose. Plz tell me if u have new suggest. tks

Answer (score 0):

Introducing your own boolean variable might help

```
class waitingThread extends Thread{

    boolean stop;

    public void run(){
        while(!stop){
            //your task
        }
     stop = false; // 
    }

    public void stopping(){
        stop= true;
    }
}
```